# ASP.NET MVC Field naming convention for nested objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, naming-conventions

I am using ASP.NET MVC 1.0.
I am creating a view to Create a new object of the following class

```
public class ClassOne
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Id {get; set; }
    public CaptionItem Caption {get; set;}
}

public class CaptionItem
{
    public string CaptionSet {get; set;}
    public string Text {get; set;}
}
```

The view will have fields to input Name, Id and the Text of the caption. On submitting the form the ClassOne object is sent to the controller which is supposed to persist the object in the database.

The question is; what should be the naming conventions used so that I can send the object to the controller as

```
public ActionResult SaveObject(ClassOne objectToSave)
```

The challenge is the Caption object

Comment: I think I have found out what the convention is. Haven't tried it out yet though.
It will be Caption.Text; the default model binder can read this correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're right, to get to Text field you have to type Caption.Text :)